# Bind Value to the Dropdown Select in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, select, dropdown

I have a JSON data wherein, I will get True/False value. Based on true/false the Select Dropdown should get selected.

Angular 16 HTML Code:

```
<select name="reportNo" id="reportNo" class="form-select" [(ngModel)]="reportInfo.active">
      <option value="true"> Activated </option>
      <option value="false"> Deactivated </option>
</select>
```

JSON:

```
"reportInfo": {
   "active": true,
}
```

If active is true then Activated should be selected otherwise false means Deactivated selected.

Comment: Hello, take a look stackblitz example, or add more details btw for me all works perfectly. Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wnnr1q?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Answer (score 0):

Code works fine, PFB working example!

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule],
  template: `
    <select name="reportNo" id="reportNo" class="bea-form-select" [(ngModel)]="reportInfo.active">
      <option value="true"> Activated </option>
      <option value="false"> Deactivated </option>
</select>  
{{reportInfo.active}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  reportInfo = {
    active: true,
  };
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-626xpz)

Comment: Thanks @Naren but its not working with separate .html file and .ts file.

Comment: @AkashM please share back the stackblitz with the issue replicated!